# Spring Security OAuth2 returning 401 Unauthorized when using dispatcher mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Please I need help on a project I'm working on. It's a Spring Boot project and I've implemented Spring Boot Security OAuth2 and everything works just fine when the OAuth2 is mounting on the root (http://localhost:8080/oauth/token) but I need everything to be accessed via (http://localhost:8080/cranoo/api/v1/oauth/token) so I read online that I have to alter the mappings of the AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer bean which I did. After I did that, the OAuth2 worked fine but other endpoints like the user accounts endpoints do not work. So I found a way to configure all endpoints using a ServletRegistrationBean and those endpoints work but the OAuth2 token endpoints stop to work and return 401. I expected that when the ServletRegistrationBean is configured with mapping everything coming from the app should be mounted on those mappings but it is not so.

Below is my code for the Dispatcher servlet.

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
    Collection<String> mappings = new ArrayList<String>();
    mappings.add("/cranoo/api/v1/*");
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet());
    registration.setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
    registration.setUrlMappings(mappings);
    return registration;
}
```

This is expected to make all endpoints accessed via http://localhost:8080/cranoo/api/v1 but when I use postman to access http://localhost:8080/cranoo/api/v1/oauth/token it returns 401 Unauthorized "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
But when I visit http://localhost:8080/cranoo/api/v1/cities it works and I get a list of all cities.

Below is my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter bean.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    static final String SIGNING_KEY = "anietie100THjjj";
    static final Integer ENCODING_STRENGTH = 256;
    static final String SECURITY_REALM = "Sprinb Boot JWT Example Realm";

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(new      ShaPasswordEncoder(ENCODING_STRENGTH));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/metrics/**", "/actuator/**", "/api-docs/**", "/login", "/register", "/oauth/token").permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .realmName(SECURITY_REALM)
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();

    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(SIGNING_KEY);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new     DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

Below is my AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer code.

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    String context = "/cranoo/api/v1";
    enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(accessTokenConverter));
    endpoints.pathMapping("/oauth/token", context + "/oauth/token");
    endpoints.pathMapping("/oauth/authorize", context + "/oauth/authorize");
    endpoints.pathMapping("/oauth/confirm_access", context + "/oauth/confirm_access");
    endpoints.pathMapping("/oauth/check_token", context + "/oauth/check_token");
    endpoints.pathMapping("/oauth/token_key", context + "/oauth/token_key");
    endpoints.pathMapping("/oauth/error", context + "/oauth/error");
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter)
            .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
```

My thinking is that since I've configured the mapping for the entire application at the DispatcherServlet I shouldn't have to put these endpoints mapping again on the AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer, and yet even if I remove all the mappings above it still doesn't work. It still returns 401. Please I need help as I've spent about four days on this and no progress.
All I want is to be able to access the token endpoint at (http://localhost:8080/cranoo/api/v1/oauth/token and other endpoints at (http://localhost:8080/cranoo/api/v1/{endpoint}

Comment: Please if you need more information about my project I will be ready to give.

Comment: Also I want to emphasize that, if I remove the servlet mapping and the endpoints mapping at AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer, visiting http://localhost:8080/oauth/token it works and http://localhost:8080/cities works as well. Also, when I put the mappings at AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer and visit http://localhost:8080/cranoo/api/v1/oauth/token it works as well but http://localhost:8080/cranoo/api/v1/cities does not work.

Comment: Also I have this on my application.properties:

security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3